# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (phone) specified for User

Tags: python, django

Iam adding a new data storage in my models.py of django but this is not working I have make migrations and everything.
models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(max_length= 1000)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="Integer")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

And this is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email','password1','password2','phone']

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','phone']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        field = ['image']
        exclude = ['fields']
```

Please help me find a solution  for this this is really stopping me to build my own website. Please tell if I should add any other details to it I will definetly do that.

Comment: `django.contrib.auth.models.User` has no field `phone` yet you put that in `fields` for your form for this model, hence you get the error.

Comment: Could you please tell me where i can edit my code?

Answer (score 1):

In your forms, you can only reference `fields` of the model you associate in the `Meta` attribute. As you are associating the forms with the `User` model, you can't access the `phone` attribute from `Post`.

Also, the `phone` really should be part of the `User` data. So you have two canonical ways of doing that. One is creating another model to store additional user data, and adding a one-to-one relationship with the `User` model. Something like this:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

The other way would be customizing the `User` class. In this case you could simply extend the `AbstractUser`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

In this case you need to add to your `settings.py`:

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.User'
```

All this information is detailed on the Django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

Answer (score 0):

By default, Django's user model does not support Phone, what you should be doing is extending the `BaseUserModel` to have your desired details.

here is a guide on [how to extend django user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/) official docs